# Adding text to an image banner

Tags: html, css

I know this question was asked here multiple times however nothing works for me. I am doing my first independent front page for one of the Codecademy exercises and I am not really fluent in coding yet. Maybe I missed something so I will paste my codes here.

```css
body, html {
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

img {
     
   width: 100%;
   height: 120px;
   object-fit: cover;
   position: relative;
   
}

 h2 {

  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: khaki;
   position: absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
<img class="background" alt="banner_html" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-2/pattern.jpeg">
<div class="companys_name">
<h2>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h2>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you, please, describe the problem. What do you want to get?

Comment: You must define top:0px; or your specific point in  h2 in the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the image as the background of the banner class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin-left: 0.5%;
            margin-right: 0.5%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5%;
            margin-top: 2%;
        }
        
        .banner {
            background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-2/pattern.jpeg);
            object-fit: cover;
            position: relative;
            height: 120px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: khaki;
            position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="companys_name">
            <h2>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks like the best option because you avoid the necessity of unnecesary properties to place the text above the image like `position: absolute`, `z-index`....

Answer (score 2):

you can insert text to images by setting position absolute and z-index to higher one. so you can display the text above the image

or you can set image as background in your text container

```
<div style='background-image: url("imageUrl");'>
   <h2>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h2>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <div style="position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index:100">
        <h2>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h2>
      </div>
    <img class="background" alt="di" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-2/pattern.jpeg">
    <div class="companys_name">
    <h2>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked when I added "top" element however I had to give it a negative value in order to position it in the center of the banner. Also "left" element was helpful in recentering the text. I am not sure if this is an efficient way to fo it but it worked so Thank You :)